# ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst tries to create a sql database

Tags: c#

`ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst` should be returning null if the provided claim is not found, however it's trying to find roles, can't find them and then tries to create an mdf file in my app_Data folder...

Should I just catch and swallow the exception or is there a way to tell it to not try to create a database file?

Here's the stack trace:

```
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\Web\App_Data' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
   at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.GetRoles()
   at System.Web.Security.RoleClaimProvider.<get_Claims>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.<get_Claims>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.FindFirst(String type)
   at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst(String type)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem. Adding following to the appSettings in web.config solved it for me

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```